# How to read specific patterns with FileReader in Java

Tags: java, filereader

I have a text file that has a repeated pattern after line 14, which does not have a fixed length.

The pattern is as follows:

```
'
String
String
Int
```

The apostrophe is used to separate each chunk of data, which I am trying to save into a Hashmap for each type (e.g one hashmap for the first line of each block, etc)

What is the best was to check if there is a block of text (is the apostrophe the best?) and then save the next three lines and continue?

Comment: Can't you use some uncommon character from the special character set. Apostrophe is a bit too common.

Comment: What about a backtick ` or some sort of complex string? I know in this case that the data will only ever be in this format or not exist at all, so I don't think it's too much of a concern in this context

Comment: It depends on the what is in the String.

Comment: why you bother yourself ? there is always a possibility for conflicting apostrophe so put an abnormal text something like this : s:?{}fh9&@#)*#@#!)(!$$    to make the possibilities to zero